# Live USB with Kali not booting

Tags: usb, kali-linux

I created a live USB according to this instructioins http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install.
I run the `dd` command on a Ubuntu 15.04 machine to create the live USB.
The operatioon seemed to have finished successful but when restarting and selecting the USB from the boot menu, the boot menu disappears for a second and then comes back again!?
[image]

I have a USB CD entry and a USB HDD entry, but both, when selecting, the menu disappears and appears shortly after again...

On the machine I am trying to install Kali, I have also installed W7 and Ubuntu 15.04 which I also performed with a Live USB!

the content after running the `dd` command of the upper folder is

```
total 584
-r--r--r-- 1 dan dan     25 Mar 12 18:51 autorun.inf
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   2048 Mar 12 18:52 boot
lr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan      1 Mar 12 18:35 debian -> .
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   2048 Mar 12 18:35 dists
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   8192 Mar 12 18:34 firmware
-r--r--r-- 1 dan dan 159564 Mar 12 18:51 g2ldr
-r--r--r-- 1 dan dan   8192 Mar 12 18:51 g2ldr.mbr
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   2048 Mar 12 18:51 install
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   2048 Mar 12 18:51 isolinux
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   2048 Mar 12 18:50 live
-r--r--r-- 1 dan dan  39734 Mar 12 18:52 md5sum.txt
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   2048 Mar 12 18:34 pool
-r--r--r-- 1 dan dan 366293 Mar 12 18:51 setup.exe
dr-xr-xr-x 1 dan dan   2048 Mar 12 18:51 tools
-r--r--r-- 1 dan dan    228 Mar 12 18:51 win32-loader.ini
```

and the content of the boot folder

```
 efi.img
```

Let me know if you need any further information

Comment: Try creating it with http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/